# How to analyze only the first and last pages of a PDF document using Azure Document Intelligence SDK

Tags: c#, azure, azure-form-recognizer, azure-ai

Is there a way to analyze only the first and last pages of a document in DotNet 7 C# program?

I tried with the below C# code but the program is only analyzing the first page and ignoring the rest of the pages

```
AnalyzeDocumentOperation operation = await client.AnalyzeDocumentFromUriAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, modelId, fileUri, new AnalyzeDocumentOptions() { Pages = { "1", "-1" } });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.ai.formrecognizer.documentanalysis.analyzedocumentoptions.pages?view=azure-dotnet#azure-ai-formrecognizer-documentanalysis-analyzedocumentoptions-pages),  `AnalyzeDocumentOptions.Pages Property` can only inputs page list or page number.

So, to process first and last page you need to mention the relevant page numbers to process specific pages.

```cs
AnalyzeDocumentOperation  lastPageOperation  =  await  client.AnalyzeDocumentFromUriAsync(WaitUntil.Completed,"prebuilt-layout", fileUri, new  AnalyzeDocumentOptions() { Pages  = { "1","10" } });
//Page 1 and Page 10(Last Page)
```

Or alternately, you can process the complete document and take the first and last page results based on count of pages.

```cs
PageResult.Pages[PageResult.Pages.Count-1] //Page Number of Last Page
```

Comment: Appreciate your response Rishab. My challenge is that not every document would have the same number of pages.