# Azure AI Search AzureOpenAIEmbeddingSkill "Concurrency conflict during operation"

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I want to index a set of documents (actually only 5) from PDF.

All I want to do is use the `TextSplitSkill` followed by `AzureOpenAIEmbeddingSkill`. Here is my Skillset template:

```
{
"name": "{{ skillSetName }}",
"description": "Skillset to chunk documents and generate embeddings",
"skills": [
    {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.SplitSkill",
        "textSplitMode": "pages",
        "defaultLanguageCode": "de",
        "maximumPageLength": 1000,
        "pageOverlapLength": 100,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "text",
                "source": "/document/content"
            }
        ],
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "textItems",
                "targetName": "pages"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.AzureOpenAIEmbeddingSkill",
        "name": "OpenAIEmbeddings",
        "description": "Convert chunk content to embeddings",
        "resourceUri": "{{ embeddingEndpoint }}",
        "deploymentId": "{{ embeddingDeployment }}",
        "context": "/document/pages/*",
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "text",
                "source": "/document/pages/*"
            }
        ],
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "embedding"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"indexProjections": {
"selectors": [
  {
    "targetIndexName": "{{ targetIndexName }}",
    "parentKeyFieldName": "parent_id",
    "sourceContext": "/document/pages/*",
    "mappings": [
      {
        "name": "content",
        "source": "/document/pages/*"
      },
      {
        "name": "content_vector",
        "source": "/document/pages/*/embedding"
      }
    ]
  }
],
"parameters": {
  "projectionMode": "skipIndexingParentDocuments"
}
```

}
}

However, I get the

**Error Message: Could not execute skill because Web Api skill response is invalid.**

**Details: Concurrency conflict during operation**

for my longest PDFs (30 pages). I read that Azure OpenAI Embedding only supports a batch-size of 16 for embeddings.

I played around with one document und splitting it into chunks of 300 chars and setting the `maximumPagesToTake` parameter to 16 but that ended in the same error.

I'm out of ideas and as the AzureOpenAIEmbeddingSkill is not open-source I can't see if they are wrapping the calls to AOI around retries / splitting them in mini-batches...

*Update*: Here a screenshot of the Indexer-Error:
[image: Error message in indexer]

Can somebody help?

Comment: the error seems like web API skill, but you are not using web API in the skill set please provide the full skill set definition

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. This is my full Skillset above. I updated the description for a screenshot of the error

Comment: I tried with your JSON template and it is working fine and I also added a target name 
```"outputs": [
        {
          "name": "embedding",
          "targetName": "embedding"
        }
      ]
    }
  ] ``` in embedded skill set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up comparing my JSON files for raw REST-API calls to the ones that are created when you use the Portal.

I finally fixed it by copying some variables from the automatically-created one to mine.

I think the key parameter that must be set is `maxPagesToTake=0`. By setting it to zero, it automatically takes all. I would have thought that would be the default behaviour, if I ddin't set it at all (but obviously my expectation was wrong).

The documentation should be updated in order to reflect the meaning of this parameter and also that it actually is a REQUIRED parameter.

Comment: That parameter is not required and the default value should be treated as 0 which is "take all" as you discovered. The error you saw seems to be some kind of transient error when calling your Azure Open AI resource to generate vector embeddings, however if you want to open a support case I can ensure that someone on our team can investigate further as it is a little bit odd.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your JSON template and it's working for me. I also added the target name.

```json
"outputs": [
        {
          "name": "embedding",
          "targetName": "embedding"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

**Output:**
[image]

If donot find Web API skills in the json

- If you want to use a Custom Web API skill in Azure AI Search, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-custom-skill-web-api).
- You can check the required template in the Azure portal.
  [image]

I have added indexes using [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.ai.formrecognizer.documentanalysis.analyzedocumentoptions.pages?view=azure-dotnet#azure-ai-formrecognizer-documentanalysis-analyzedocumentoptions-pages). The `AnalyzeDocumentOptions.Pages Property` can accept a page list or a page number as inputs.

```
public System.Collections.Generic.IList<string> Pages { get; }
```

Integrate the `AnalyzeDocumentOptions.Pages` property into the existing code and limit the analysis to only the first 5 pages.

```
var options = new AnalyzeDocumentOptions { Pages = { "1","2" , "3" ,"4" ,"5" } }
```

I tried a sample example from Azure Samples search with dotnet using [git](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/search-dotnet-getting-started/tree/master) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77393541/how-to-analyze-only-the-first-and-last-pages-of-a-pdf-document-using-azure-docum).

```
  var schedule = new IndexingSchedule(TimeSpan.FromDays(1))
  {
      StartTime = DateTimeOffset.Now
  };
  var parameters = new IndexingParameters()
  {
      BatchSize = 100,
      MaxFailedItems = 0,
      MaxFailedItemsPerBatch = 0
  };
  var indexer = new SearchIndexer("hotels-sql-idxr", dataSource.Name, searchIndex.Name)
  {
      Description = "Data indexer",
      Schedule = schedule,
      Parameters = parameters,
      FieldMappings =
      {
          new FieldMapping("_id") {TargetFieldName = "HotelId"},
          new FieldMapping("Amenities") {TargetFieldName = "Tags"}
      }
  };
```

```
Console.WriteLine("Running Azure SQL indexer...");
try
{
    await indexerClient.RunIndexerAsync(indexer.Name);
}
catch (RequestFailedException ex) when (ex.Status == 429)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to run indexer: {0}", ex.Message);
}
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

// Document analysis
var options = new AnalyzeDocumentOptions { Pages = { "1-5" } };
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for looking into it! Yes, If I limit the maximum number of pages to e.g. 5, it works. But I am dealing with long PDFs >30 pages and I want all the information of course.

I do not find WebApi Skills either, I don't want any at this time. This is why this error message is driving me crazy

Comment: glad that u resolved by adjusting the maxPagesToTake parameter to `0  `